# How do I know that the Soundpool is ready using SDK target below 2.2?

Tags: java, android, sdk, target, soundpool

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236070/sound-works-on-htc-desire-but-not-on-t-mobile-g1).

I managed to modify my code to use SoundPool instead of AudioManager. Know it works more or less.

```
public class Sound {

    private static boolean sound = true;

    private static final int EAT_SOUND = 1;
    private static final int SHORT_EAT_SOUND = 2;
    private static final int EAT_CHERRY_SOUND = 3;
    private static final int EAT_GHOST_SOUND = 4;
    private static final int EXTRA_LIVE_SOUND = 5;
    private static final int INTERMISSION_SOUND = 6;
    private static final int OPENING_SOUND = 7;
    private static final int PACMAN_DIES_SOUND = 8;
    private static final int SIREN_SOUND = 9;

    private static Context context;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

    public static void initializeOpenSound(Context con) {
        context = con;
        soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 100);
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundPoolMap.put(OPENING_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.opening_song, 1));
    }

    public static void initializeSounds() {
        soundPoolMap.put(EAT_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.eating, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(SHORT_EAT_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.eating_short, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(EAT_CHERRY_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.eating_cherry, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(EAT_GHOST_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.eating_ghoasts, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(EXTRA_LIVE_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.extra_lives, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(INTERMISSION_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.intermission, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(PACMAN_DIES_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.pac_man_dies, 1));
        soundPoolMap.put(SIREN_SOUND, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.siren, 1));
    }

    private static void playSound(int sound) {
        int streamID = soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(sound), 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1f);
        if (sound == OPENING_SOUND) {
            soundPool.setLoop(streamID, 2);
        }
    }

    public static void playSirenSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(SIREN_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Siren sound");
                playSound(SIREN_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Siren Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playPacmanDiesSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(PACMAN_DIES_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Pacman Dies sound");
                playSound(PACMAN_DIES_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Pacman Dies Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playOpeningSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(OPENING_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Opening sound");
                playSound(OPENING_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Opening Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playIntermissionSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(INTERMISSION_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Intermission sound");
                playSound(INTERMISSION_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Intermission Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playExtraLiveSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(EXTRA_LIVE_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Extra Live sound");
                playSound(EXTRA_LIVE_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Extra Live Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playEatSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(EAT_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Eat Sound");
                playSound(EAT_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Eat Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playShortEatSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(SHORT_EAT_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Short Eat sound");
                playSound(SHORT_EAT_SOUND);
            } else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Short Eat Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playEatCherrySound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(EAT_CHERRY_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Eat Cherry sound");
                playSound(EAT_CHERRY_SOUND);
            }  else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Eat Cherry Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playEatGhostSound() throws SoundInitializationError {
        if (isSoundOn()) {
            if (soundPoolMap.containsKey(EAT_GHOST_SOUND)) {
                System.out.println("Play Eat Ghost sound");
                playSound(EAT_GHOST_SOUND);
            }  else {
                throw new SoundInitializationError("Eat Ghost Sound not initialized!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isSoundOn() {
        return sound;
    }

    public static void setSoundOn(boolean b) {
        sound = b;
    }

}
```

However, I have a more or less big audio file which I want to play during startup. However if i call initializeOpenSound() and then playOpening Sound(), then the sound isn't played and logcat outputs:

```
07-15 09:11:02.121: WARN/SoundPool(14273):   sample 1 not READY
```

In SDK 2.2 I would use [SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener.html) but how can I achieve the same using SDK 2.1?

Edit: I would also be happy width a solution that doesn't include a listener or something like that, but either try to play the sound file until it was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read if you try to play the sound right after initializing it, it won't be ready and you will get this error. You could make a loading page and just wait for a few seconds until you are sure the sound has loaded.

Also make sure your filesize isn't over 1048576 bytes, thats the limitation for Soundpool. If you want to play background music or something i think you have to use media player.

Comment: yes wait a few seconds was also my idea. but i tried it with 1 seconds and 10 seconds but nothing worked....

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a fallback implementation for OnLoadCompleteListener which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692572/knowing-if-the-loading-of-a-sound-with-soundpool-has-been-successful-on-android-1).