# Forever playing without pause in Android

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I have a problem. When I try to play sound using Soundpool there is small pause between each playing.
For example, I have 2 sec-sound which I want to play when button is pressed.
I tried to start 2 threads with the same sound. Second started 0.5 sec after first. But there is no helpful.

```
    AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    SoundPool mSoundPool;
    Runnable thr1;
    Runnable thr2;

    public void playLoopedSound(int soundId) {
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)*2; 
        thr1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mSoundPool.play(soundId, 0, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f); //0 = no loop, -1 = loop forever
            }
        };


   thr2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mSoundPool.play(soundId, 0, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f); 
        }
    };
    thr1.run();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(400);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        thr2.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without debugging, but I've had similar issues due to the performance of soundpool when it's loading sounds.  To get around this, I implemented SoundPool.onLoadCompleteListener to ensure that I didn't start trying to play sounds until the soundpool was fully loaded.

Be aware that this is only available on API8 or above.  See this answer for a nice implementation:

[Knowing if the loading of a sound with SoundPool has been successful on Android 1.6/2.0/2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692572/knowing-if-the-loading-of-a-sound-with-soundpool-has-been-successful-on-android)